# Why do I get a CSP Report for blocked_uri "blob"?

Tags: content-security-policy

I get the following CSP-Report

```
{
  "csp-report":{
    "document-uri":"https://example.com/somepage",
    "blocked-uri":"blob",
    "violated-directive":"script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: data:",
    "effective-directive":"script-src",
    "original-policy": myCSPPolicyRuleHere,
    "status-code":200
  }
}
```

I cannot reproduce this error on various Browser. The Report comes from all kinds of Pages we have. (Our Main Page, Forum, Static Landingpages)

It could be a kind of Extension (which?).

The (very usefull) Project "CSP-usefull" has collected a lot of WTF CSP Reports. But I coulnd find anything about "blob" there.
https://github.com/nico3333fr/CSP-useful/tree/master/csp-wtf

(I know that our CSP-Rule is very relaxed atm. But this is just the first iteration we deployed live)